# Trying to understand pointer to a pointer with 2d vertor

Tags: c++

I am pretty new to C++ and am having trouble understanding how to initiate a pointer to a pointer with a 2d vector. I have searched quite a bit and can't seem to find the solution to my problem. In my case, the original 2d vector is set up in the `main` and is passed to a sub by reference. In that sub I want to set up another pointer to send to multiple other sub routines.

Below is a simplified representation of the code. I get an error in the sub at `dblptr[0][0] = 3;`. The error is:

> E0349 no operator "=" matches these operands

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;


vector<vector<double>> *dblptr;

void SetDblPtr(vector<vector<double>> &arr)
{

    dblptr = &arr;
    dblptr[0][0] = 3;

}


int main()
{
    vector<vector<double>> arr(3, vector<double>(3));

    arr = { {1,2,3}, {1,2,3},{1,2,3} };

    SetDblPtr(arr);

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you want to use pointers here?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, there is no reason to use a single pointer in your code.

Next, a `std::vector` is not a c-array, it contains more than only the data (eg size and capacity). You cannot take the address of a vector and then use pointer arithmetics as you are attempting to. If you want to do it then use `data()` it returns you a pointer to the vectos underlying data:

```
 vector<vector<double>> arr(3, vector<double>(3));
 auto fourth_element = arr.data()[3];
```

The fourth element of a `vector<vector<double>>` is a `vector<double>` and again you cannot use pointer arithmetics on that (see above). To get the first double via pointer arithemtics you would do:

```
 double x = arr.data()[0].data()[0];
                  //^--  pointer to array
                  //   ^-- first element of that array (ie a vector<double>)
                  //          ^-- pointer to array
                  //             ^-- first element of that array (ie a double)
```

Seeing this it should become obvious, that what you get is mainly obfuscated syntax. With vectors you should prefer to use its `operator[]`:

```
double y = arr[0][0];
```

Effectively its the same, you just dont have to go through hoops of indirection using pointers.

**TL;DR**: No reason to use pointers here. The assignment should be:

```
arr[0][0] = 3;
```

**PS**: One reason why `std::vector` is such a great container is its data locality. However, as the elements are stored on the heap, a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` looses this big advantage and often it is better to use a flat `std::vector<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

This line causes the problem:

```
dblptr[0][0] = 3;
```

replace it with:

```
(*dblptr)[0][0] = 3;
```